# Google Docs Apps Script сохранение определенных страниц в PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста мне необходимо,чтобы посредством GAS выполнялось конвертирование doc в pdf и сохранялось в папке на Google Drive в какой-нибудь папке "Work", НО самое важное у меня получилось сделать определенный doc  с определенным ID сконвертировать полностью(весь документ), а мне необходимо чтобы он по очереди все .doc файлы из папки сохранял в pdf со страницами 18-21(например), т.е. не весь документ

Answer (score 0):

Средствами Google Apps Script этого сделать невозможно. Документ на печать поставляется целиком в формате pdf, далее уже средствами печати на стороне клиента назначаются параметры печати.

Т.о. чтобы использовать этот процесс в облаке вам необходимо иметь сервер, который будет принимать Документ и параметры для печати. Этот же сервер, после того как он разобьет на нужные страницы, должен будет обратно сохранить файл на ваш Диск.

На первый взгляд кажется, что Google Cloud Functions или Google Cloud Run могут решить эту проблему.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто вроде как можно указывать доп.параметры при сохранении,думал что впринципе есть какой-то способ сохранит ьв пдф определенные страницы с app script

Comment: К сожалению, только так.